# How do I install mod_wsgi to xampp server on Ubuntu? Running into libtool errors

Tags: python, linux, apache, xampp, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to add Python and `mod_wsgi` to an XAMPP/LAMPP server. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10. To do so, I'm following [these instructions](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=42975).

```
cd /opt/lampp
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.1/Python-2.7.1.tgz
tar xzf Python-2.7.1.tgz -C /opt/lampp
cd Python-2.7.1
./configure --prefix=/opt/lampp --enable-shared
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lampp/lib:/usr/lib/:/usr/local/lib:/var/lib
export LD_RUN_PATH=/opt/lampp/lib:$LD_RUN_PATH
make
sudo make install
```

After `make`, I get the following error:

```
mod_wsgi-3.3 $ make
/opt/lampp/bin/apxs -c -I/opt/lampp/include/python2.7 -DNDEBUG   mod_wsgi.c -L/opt/lampp/lib -L/opt/lampp/lib/python2.7/config  -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/opt/lampp/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -prefer-pic -I/opt/lampp/include/c-client -I/opt/lampp/include/libpng -I/opt/lampp/include/freetype2 -O3 -fPIC -L/opt/lampp/lib -I/opt/lampp/include -I/opt/lampp/include/ncurses  -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -I/opt/lampp/include  -I/opt/lampp/include/apr-1   -I/opt/lampp/include/apr-1 -I/opt/lampp/include -I/opt/lampp/include/python2.7 -DNDEBUG  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1555: /opt/lampp/build/libtool: preserve_args+= --silent: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= gcc: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 2419: /opt/lampp/build/libtool: later+= -prefer-pic: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -std=gnu99: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/opt/lampp/include/c-client: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/opt/lampp/include/libpng: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/opt/lampp/include/freetype2: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -O3: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -fPIC: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -L/opt/lampp/lib: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/opt/lampp/include: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/opt/lampp/include/ncurses: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -DLINUX=2: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -D_REENTRANT: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -D_GNU_SOURCE: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -pthread: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/opt/lampp/include: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/opt/lampp/include/apr-1: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/opt/lampp/include/apr-1: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/opt/lampp/include: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I/opt/lampp/include/python2.7: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -DNDEBUG: not found
/opt/lampp/build/libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -c: not found
libtool: compile: you must specify a compilation command
libtool: compile: Try `libtool --help --mode=compile' for more information.
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

I looked up "command failed with rc=65536". The forums I read said it usually indicates that the Python files are 32bit, when the server and `mod_wsgi` is 64bit. I went back and re-installed the 64bit version of Python.

Also, I double-checked that I have `libtool` installed, using `sudo apt-get install libtool`, but I checked `/opt/lampp/build/libtool` and that folder/files don't exist, so perhaps the issue is that I don't have `libtool` installed to the server? If that is the issue, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Some Apache distributions such as lampp are incomplete and do not provide all the parts which you need to build other Apache modules yourself. This for you appears to include the libtool software they used to build Apache originally. You need to complain to the lampp software maintainers as to why their package is incomplete. Better still, just use the OS supplied packages for Apache.